# C++: Function call by value or by reference? (polymorphism)

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, polymorphism

Sorry if the name is a bit confusing.
I come from a Java Background, but I've noticed that polymorphism is handled a little differently in C++

I have the code below;

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    void printOut()
    {
        std::cout << "this is the Base Class" << endl;
    }
};


class DerivedClass :
    public BaseClass
{
public:
    void printOut()
    {
        std::cout << "this is the Derived Class" << endl;
    }
};
```

These are two simple classes I've created to test polymorphism with.

The main function is as follows

```
BaseClass base;
base.printOut();

DerivedClass derived;
derived.printOut();

BaseClass *pBase = &derived;
pBase->printOut();
```

The output I get from this is;

```
this is the Base Class
this is the Derived Class
this is the Base Class
```

Coming from a Java background, this is a bit odd to me as even though I have upcasted the derived class, it should still print `this is the Derived Class` as it's content should still be the Derived Class, but with a different identification.

However, in this case, it was not as I expected, and it seems to have gone by it's pointer definition, and printed `this is the Base Class` instead.

How would i achieve the desired result in C++?

Comment: For polymorphism to apply to a member function, it must be made `virtual`.

Comment: Oh, yeah that fixed it. thank you very much!